# Limit author list in reference using natbib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am writing my thesis using `natbib` with `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`. I want the **reference list (bibliography)** to obey the following rules:

1. Show all authors names when the author number is less than 5.
2. Show "first author et al" when author number is greater than 4.

I do not want to change the citation appearance in the text.
I am very very confused while finding a solution for the above. I am in a little bit hurry. Kindly help me and please do not scold.

```
\documentclass[openright, twoside, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amstext,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure,float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{physics}


\usepackage{float}


\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}   


\usepackage{makecell}


\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{cover/title}


\begin{spacing}{1.5}

\tableofcontents 


\pagenumbering{arabic} 

\include{cover/def} %include all the definitions
\include{chapter_01/introduction}


\appendix

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{thesis_bib}

\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While your question is fairly clear as it is now, you can increase your chances of getting a good answer quickly by providing us with an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). If you add an MWE to your question we won't lose time recreating a short example document that you already have and can get started more quickly to write the answer that you desire.

Comment: I have given one

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an MWE: It is not minimal, because it loads packages that have nothing to do with the bibliography. And it is not working: We have none of the `\include`d files and we also don't have your example `.bib` entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see there is no convenient option to do this, you have to modify the `.bst` style.

1. Locate `abbrvnat.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich abbrvnat.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/abbrvnat.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine.
3. Rename the file to `abbrvnat-maxbibnames4.bst` (this is a requirement of the license for `abbrvnat.bst`, a modified version of `abbrvnat.bst` should not bear the same name)
4. Open the file and find the function `FUNCTION {format.names}` (in my version ll. 216-243) and replace the entire block with

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.names}
   { 's :=
     #1 'nameptr :=
     s num.names$ 'numnames :=
     numnames 'namesleft :=
       { namesleft #0 > }
       { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
         nameptr #1 >
           { namesleft #1 >
               { ", " * t * }
               { numnames #2 >
                   { "," * }
                   'skip$
                 if$
                 t "others" =
                   { " et~al." * }
                   { " and " * t * }
                 if$
               }
             if$
           }
           { 
             t
             namesleft #4 >
               { " et al."  *
                 #1 'namesleft := }
               'skip$
             if$
           }
         if$
         nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
         namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
       }
     while$
   }
   ```
5. Add your name and date and explain the modification in the comments at the top of the file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-maxbibnames4}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` in your document.

Comment: Superb. I have never had a more guided help.